# Using DocumentDB with Forms Authentication and Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to store my user data from external authentication services in DocumentDB. After successfully login into Google, I got this error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed." What am I doing wrong?

This is the source code error:

```
// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
switch (result)
{
```

Part of the stack trace:

> [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName) +948663
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type
>   type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup) +84
>
> [ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client' is either not registered in the
>   machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the
>   inner exception for details.]

Here are some snippets of my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="AccountEndpoint=[blah]" providerName="Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"/>

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
```

DocumentDB works fine when doing CRUD with other data using my repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box membership/role/etc asp.net provider for DocumentDB. You'd need to create your own custom provider for it.

Comment: There are a number of community published ASP.NET identity providers available today - https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=documentdb+asp